# how to write dictionary of tuple and list as key value in a text file

Tags: python

I have a big dictionary:

```
abig = {('WhatsappUnameP', 'DOB', 'FriendMode', 'GroupName'): ['WhatsappUnameP', 'DOB', 'FriendName', 'FriendLoc', 'FriendEventMessage', 'FriendMode', 'GroupName']}
```

Now I am opening a file and writing this dictionary using JSON.

```
with open(str(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),outputfilename)),'w') as filewritehandle:
    print("NA")
    filewritehandle.write(json.dumps(abig))
```

Above code does not write data in file writes and give typeerror.

Comment: please fix the indentation of you code. Also you need to share the relevant error message with your `TypeError`

Comment: Why don't you use `json.dump`, which can write straight to a file? Also note the requirement for a [mcve] including the actual output.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: keys must be a string

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, json dict doesn't support tuple, list, sets or dict as key.
Use a string or a numerical value.

Comment: can I use something else like pickle

Answer (score 0):

yep pickle works for that:

```
import pickle
abig = {('WhatsappUnameP', 'DOB', 'FriendMode', 'GroupName'): ['WhatsappUnameP', 'DOB', 'FriendName', 'FriendLoc', 'FriendEventMessage', 'FriendMode', 'GroupName']}
filename = "c:/temp/test.p"
# record pickle
with open(filename, "w") as output_file:
    my_pickle = pickle.Pickler(output_file)
    my_pickle.dump(abig)

# load pickle
with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
    my_pickle = pickle.Unpickler(input_file)
    data = my_pickle.load()
    print data
```